# Running jboss 6.0

Tags: java, jboss6.x

i got the following error can u help me out

```
18:20:29,504 WARN  [org.jboss.deployers.vfs.structure] Exception looking for WEB-INF/lib, /C:/eTravel_workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.jboss.ide.eclipse.as.core/JBoss_6.0_Runtime_9_Server1294231790973/deploy/eTravel.war, java.util.zip.ZipException: error in opening zip file
18:23:28,990 INFO  [org.jboss.jpa.deployment.PersistenceUnitDeployment] Starting persistence unit persistence.unit:unitName=eTravel.war#eTravel
18:23:28,990 ERROR [org.jboss.kernel.plugins.dependency.AbstractKernelController] Error installing to Start: name=persistence.unit:unitName=eTravel.war#eTravel state=Create: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider cannot be cast to javax.persistence.spi.PersistenceProvider
    at org.jboss.jpa.builder.DefaultCEMFBuilder.build(DefaultCEMFBuilder.java:46) [:1.0.2-alpha-1]
```

Answer (score 3):

You probably have a copy of the JPA JAR(s) in your WAR. Remove them. JBoss has its own copy, and they will clash.

Comment: +1 Thank you. I had the same problem in Websphere but it is solved by just removing the jpa jar inside the WAR.